# How to estimate Poisson process using R? (Or: how to use NHPoisson package?)

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I have a database of events (i.e. a variable of dates) and associated covariates.

The events are generated by the non-stationary Poisson process with parameter being an unknown (but possibly linear) function of some covariates.

I think the NHPoisson package exists just for this purpose; but after 15 hours of unsuccessful research I am still nowhere near getting to know how to use it.

Heck, I even tried reading both referenced books:
Coles, S. (2001). An introduction to statistical modelling of extreme values. Springer. 
Casella, G. and Berger, R.L., (2002). Statistical inference. Brooks/Cole.

The one single example in the documentation of fitPP.fun doesn't seem to fit my setup; I don't have extreme values! I just have bare events.

Can anyone please help me with a simple example of fitting a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ with single covariate $X$, and assumption, that $\lambda = \lambda_0 + \alpha \cdot X$? I'm interested in estimation of $\lambda_0$ and $\alpha$. I provide a two-column data set with times of events (let say, measured in seconds after some arbitrary time $t_0$) and another column with values of the covariate $X$?

Comment: For those interested, I'm working on a rewrite of this library to improve usability. https://github.com/statwonk/NHPoisson

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Fitting a stationary Poisson process

First of all it is important to realize, what sort of input data NHPoisson needs.

Foremost, NHPoisson needs a list of **indices** of event moments. If we record time interval and number of events in the time interval, than I we must translate it into a single column of dates, possibly "smearing" the dates over the interval they are recorded on.

For the simplicity I'll assume, that we use time measured in seconds, and that the "second" is the natural unit of $\lambda$.

Let's simulate data for a simple, stationary Poisson process, which has $\lambda=1$ events per minute:

```
lambda=1/60 #1 event per minute
time.span=60*60*24 #24 hours, with time granularity one second

aux<-simNHP.fun(rep(lambda,time.span))
```

The `simNHP.fun` makes the simulation. We use to get `aux$posNH`, a variable with *indices* of moments of simulated event firing. We can see that we roughly have 60*24 = 1440 events, by checking `length(aux$posNH).

Now let's reverse-engineer the $\lambda$ with `fitPP.fun`:

```
out<-fitPP.fun(posE=aux$posNH,n=time.span,start=list(b0=0)) # b0=0 is our guess at initial value for optimization, which is internally made with `nlminb` function
```

Because the function only takes events' indices, it needs also a measure of how many possible indices are possible. And **this is a very confusing part**, because in the true Poisson process it is possible to have **infinite number of possible events** (if only $\lambda>0$). But from the perspective of the `fitPP` we need to choose some small enough time unit. We choose it so small, that we can assume maximum one event per unit of time.

So what we do in fact is that we **approximate** the Poisson process with granular sequence of binomial events, each event spans exactly one unit of time, in analogy to the mechanism in which Poisson distribution can be seen as a limit of binomial distribution in [the law of rare events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Derivation_of_Poisson_distribution_.E2.80.94_The_law_of_rare_events).

Once we understand it, the rest is much simpler (at least for me).

To get the approximation of our $\lambda$ me need to take exponent of the fitted parameter `beta`, `exp(coef(out)[1])`. **And here comes another important piece of information, that is missing in the manual**: with `NHPoisson` we fit to the *logarithm* of $\lambda$, not to $\lambda$ itself.

### Fitting a non-stationary Poisson process

`NHPoisson` fits the following model:

$\lambda = \exp(\vec{P}^T \cdot \vec{\beta} )$

i.e. it fits linear combination of parameters $\vec{P}$ (called covariates) to the *logarithm* of the $\lambda$.

Now let's prepare non-stationary Poisson process.

```
time.span=60*60*24 #24 hours, with time granularity one second
all.seconds<-seq(1,time.span,length.out=time.span)
lambdas=0.05*exp(-0.0001*all.seconds) #we can't model a linear regression with NHPoisson. It must have the form with exp.
aux<-simNHP.fun(lambdas)
```

Just as before, `aux$posNH` would give us indices of events, but this time we will notice, that the intensity of the events diminish exponentially with time. And the rate of this diminishing is a parameter we want to estimate.

```
out<-fitPP.fun(tind=TRUE,covariates=cbind(all.seconds),
        posE=aux$posNH,
        start=list(b0=0,b1=0),modSim=TRUE)
```

It is important to note, that we need to put `all.seconds` as a covariate, not `lambdas`. The exponentiation/logaritmization is done internally by the `fitPP.fun`. BTW, apart from predicted values, the function makes two graphs by default.

The last piece is a swiss-knife function for model validation, `globalval.fun`.

```
aux<-globalval.fun(obFPP=out,lint=2000,
        covariates=cbind(all.seconds),typeI='Disjoint',
        typeRes='Raw',typeResLV='Raw',resqqplot=FALSE)
```

Among other things, the function divides the time into intervals, each `lint` samples long, so it is possible to create crude graphs that compare predicted intensity with observed intensity.

Comment: Great explanations Adam, thank you very much. I'm under the impression we cannot fit a model with two groups of individuals and one intensity per group, am I right ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You can model group membership as a covariate, and - yes, you can add covariates. There can be different events' intensity for one group and different for the other. I've never done something like that, though.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I see how to put one "intercept" per group, e.g. an intensity having form $\lambda_i(t)=\exp(a_i+bt)$, but I don't see how to put one slope $b_i$ per group.

Comment: Adam, maybe I was confused. Now I'm under the impression there's no problem. I'll come back later in case of need. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: very good answer! btw,
    > out<-fitPP.fun(posE=aux$posNH,n=time.span,beta=0)  
    Error in fitPP.fun(posE = aux$posNH, n = time.span, beta = 0) :  
      argument "start" is missing, with no default

Comment: The interface of fitPP.fun is slightly changed now, it would be great if you could adjust a little bit your cool answer :)

Comment: @vak Thank you very much for your edits. I haven't used the `NHPoisson` since the time the post was written, so I didn't know about the changes. If it was possible I would cede the ownership of this question to you, so you would get a due credit for maintaining the post updated.

Comment: @adam, Witam :) Your great post was the only helper to approach to NHPoisson over the whole Internet, many thanks for it! It made my weekend. Well, the only thing that I successfully managed so far, was the case with covariates=NULL. I still can't manage the case even with ONE covariate. The globalval.fun is also spitting me errors :( if you have about 5 minutes look at this, please, maybe you'll see where is my mistake, but don't tell me it is in my DNA ;) http://pastebin.com/KQCL0H2e . Even one covariate is not reverse-engineered.

Comment: @vak I am living for a week. I will be able to look at it after next monday. Sorry.

Comment: no prob, waiting. Damn, as @StéphaneLaurent mentioned, λ=exp(b0 + b1*covariate1 + ... bN * covariateN) it means that the model is rather "multiplicative" and even a simple mixture of two NHPPs can't be well modeled...

Comment: @vak Yes, it is multiplicative. For full control over the model try Bayesian methods. I believe the problem is Stan-compatible, and Stan (http://mc-stan.org) is usually faster then JAGS. And arguably Bayesian approach offer more advantages than disadvantages.

Comment: A potential editor notes that, "changes to `fitPP.fun` have made the previous suggestion of `exp(out$beta)` stop working".

Comment: To access the information saved in "out" you have to use now "@", e.g. the coefficients are accessed using "out@coef".