How to test if the frequency of events (gradient) changes over time?
I have time-series data in Python that tracks specific actions over time, with . I’ve quantified these actions and would like to test if the frequency of these events per unit of time (so basically the gradient) statistically changes as time progresses. Basically, I assume there is a decrease in the gradient over time but I want to test whether this is statistically true.
Basically, I assume there is a decrease in the gradient over time, but I want to test whether this is statistically true.
The data consists of timestamps and a column indicating whether the action occurs at that timestamp. Some timestamps have repeated occurrences of events (grouped with the same ID), while other timestamps are empty or contain a single occurrence. What statistical methods (and libraries in Python) would be best suited for this analysis?
data = {
    'timestamp': [
        '00:01', '00:02', '00:03', '00:04', '00:05', 
        '00:06', '00:07', '00:08', '00:09', '00:10', 
        '00:11', '00:12', '00:13', '00:14', '00:15'
    ],
    'event_group': [
        1, 1, '', '', 2, 
        2, 2, '', '', 
        '', 3, '', '', 4, 4
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Could you elaborate on this "event_group" coding and what "repeated occurrences of events" might mean? This dataset sounds more complex than what you otherwise describe and that can make a huge difference in how the data can be analyzed.

You could see it as a cumulative event counter, with events having a certain duration, which is what I mean by repeated occurance. You can basically ignore the duration of an event_group and only look at their first timestamp.

I assume that in your example data, if the "event_group" value is a 4, it means that 4 events happened in that uniy of time? In this case, good OLS would tell you what you want: is the slope of the linear fitpositive or negative, and is the coefficient statistically significant?

Would I be correct, then, in supposing that your data could be fully reproduced by simply having a list of the timestamps when actions occurred?  My concern is whether and to what extent multiple events might happen simultaneously.  Another concern, as suggested by language like "specific actions" and "event group," is whether you are tracking multiple types of events.

The number of 'event_group' is the cumulative value, so this is only an ID for me to know which event occured when. Its value does therefore only reflect the cumulative event counter and only represents a single event, and there is only one type of event and no events can occur simultaneously. So e.g. event_group 3 is the same as 4, apart from their duration (which you can ignore) and their ID (which you can also ignore).

It would be best to include that information in the post itself.  Assuming the waiting time of each event is independent of its predecessor, you ask about testing whether the events are governed by a homogeneous Poisson process or an inhomogeneous one.  That can be readily analyzed and tested with, say, a likelihood ratio test, and in a very flexible way using regression techniques: e.g., regress the waiting times against the time of the preceding event using a specified function and a conditional Exponential response.

The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/150953 appears to ask exactly the same question.  Is that correct, or does your differ from that one?
